# Cannot get date to be logged in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I've the following logging configuration:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.dashboard: debug
    org:
      springframework:
        jdbc:
          core:
            JdbcTemplate: debug
            StatementCreatorUtils: trace
  pattern:
#    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
#    dateformat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
#    console: '%date{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", UTC} [%p] [%t] %M\(%F:%L\) - %msg%n'
#    console: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
```

However when I run the app I don't see dates in the log:

```
11:55:13,589 DEBUG [ ...
```

I've tried different values and combinations of the `pattern.console` and `pattern.dateformat` above but they haven't any effect.

Interesting that the option

```
logging:
  level:
    com.dashboard: debug
```

does have an effect. It's the app package and it's logged in debug level. When it's turned off it's not logged.

slf4j is used.

The problem is that the app is a gradle project that uses other gradle projects as dependencies and they seem to use all possible existing loggers/libs. I ran `gradle dependencies` on the app and then used grep to see what it has.

Here is an exceprt:

```
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |         |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |         |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.11.1
|    |    |         |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |         |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |         |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.4 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.0 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    |              \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    |    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
...
```

I'm not sure whether some of their configurations has a higher priority than the configuration in `application.yml` of my app...

But I was sure that settings in my app should override everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41414366/log4j2-date-conversion-pattern-does-not-work I configured my xml and the date's picked up

Comment: @Paul unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part was to understand what logger/configuration influenced the behavior. So I decided to `grep` for `hh:mm:ss,SSS` (the comma as delimiter between secs and ms was seen in the log) in the project directory. The result was 3 logback.xml files in other modules. There was no date format in them. I created logback.xml in my app module and included date format. After that dates appeared in console output.